# How to expand a column of Null, Record, and List types?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

How can I `Expand` a column in Power Query that contains `Record`, `List`, and `null` values in it?

If the column was all one type (like for instance `Record`), I could click here to expand the column values:

[image: picture1]

...but the column I'm trying to expand doesn't have that little dropdown button, so I likely have to hard code the expansion somehow:

[image: picture2]

The `Record` values have this kind of data in them:

[image: picture3]

...and the `List`'s contain `Record`'s.

So I don't know if I need some kind of recursion function here to expand them all or what, but I was trying to follow [this answer](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/expanding-column-with-record-and-list-together/m-p/1726076#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20Value.Type%20in%20a%20custom%20column,%28%5BCustom%5D%29%20%3D%20List.Type%20then%20%5BCustom%5D%20else%20%7B%20%5BCustom%5D%7D), but it doesn't quite align with my use case as I already have data in my tables, vs the answer putting in fake data to the `Custom` column (i.e. `each if [Column1] = "List" then {[A=1], [A = 2]} else [A=3]),`????).

My attempt at it looks like this, however it results in a red and white bar across the top of my rows when run:

```
...
    // Convert the API Response data to a table (of lists)
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(GeneratedList, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    
    // Expand to get 1 column of Record types
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1"),
    
    // Expand those records into their own columns, we need to target Column1.target
    #"Expanded Column2" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Column1", "Column1", {"_links", "id", "type", "emitted_at", "conversation", "source", "target"}, {"Column1._links", "Column1.id", "Column1.type", "Column1.emitted_at", "Column1.conversation", "Column1.source", "Column1.target"}),
    
    // At this point, Column1.target is a column of null and Record value types. Expand it again
    #"Expanded Column1.target" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Column2", "Column1.target", {"data"}, {"Column1.target.data"}),
    
    // Now we need to target Column1.target.data, which is the column that has Record, List, AND null types
    #"Added NEWEXPANDEDCOLUMN" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Column1.target", #"Expanded Column1.target.data.NEW", each if Value.Type([#"Expanded Column1.target.data"]) = List.Type then [#"Expanded Column1.target.data"] else {[#"Expanded Column1.target.data"]})
in
    #"Added NEWEXPANDEDCOLUMN"
```

I want to get that last column all expanded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the list items are lists of records, you can

- Remove the nulls
- Extract the records from the lists in the column
- Convert to table
- Expand the records

*Code assumes the records in the List are the same as the stand alone records.  If not, we can add a step to extract the field names (or you can select "load more" from the expand dialog*

```
let

//First two lines are just to produce an example similar to yours
    Source = {
        [a=1, b=2, c=3],
        [a=4,b=5,c=6],
        null,
        {[a=10,b=20,c=30],
        [a=40,b=50,c=60]},
        null
                },
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),

//Remove the nulls
    #"Remove Nulls" = List.RemoveNulls(#"Converted to Table"[Column1]),

//extract the records from the List items
    #"Transform List to Record" = List.Transform(#"Remove Nulls", each  if Value.Type(_) = type list then 
        List.Accumulate(_,[],(s,c)=> s & c) else _),

//Convert to table and expand
    #"Converted to Table1" = Table.FromList(#"Transform List to Record", Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table1", "Column1", {"a", "b", "c"})
in
    #"Expanded Column1"
```